# Laptop will not wake from suspend with usb-keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard, suspend

The actually weird thing is that my usb-keyboard shows as wakeup enabled.

> grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product

outputs

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2/product:Mechanical Keyboard
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-3/product:USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/product:EHCI Host Controller
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/product:xHCI Host Controller
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/product:xHCI Host Controller
```

and

> grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup

outputs

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-3/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-5/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/power/wakeup:disabled
```

Now, I admit, my laptop setup is a little weird in that I have disconnected both the laptop screen, built-in keyboard and touchpad. I only reconnect them prior to travelling and then, only reluctantly.
But that shouldn't matter because,

a) it has presented no other problems

b) *when* I reconnect them, waking from the usb-keyboard *still* doesn't work. Waking from the built-in keyboard works just fine.

I run Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and always avoid major under the hood tinkering if I can, if that helps. The laptop is an Acer Travelmate p256-mg.

Comment: How do you wake the machine? Do you need to hit the power button or do something else?

Comment: Usb-keyboard (and mouse) can't wake it, so yes, powerbutton.

Comment: Cool. Reason I ask is because I've seen this with an HP and Dell in the past. Will write an answer that will *hopefully* work for you as well 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that I have seen in the past on an HP ProBook and a Dell Precision notebook. The issue came down to the machine not *quite* going to sleep and, because it wasn't sleeping, it couldn't be woken with a keypress from an external keyboard. Like your machine, though, the built-in keyboard would allow the machine to resume. In the end, the solution was to modify Grub a bit.

Here is how you can do it, too:

0. Open a Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Open `/etc/default/grub` for editing with `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /etc/default/grub
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your editor of choice.</sup>

   Find the line that starts `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. You will be adding settings to this line. Be sure to leave any existing values untouched.
2. If you have an Nvidia video adapter, add `rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1` to the end of the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` value. For example:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1"
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** There are instances where an Nvidia device can prevent a machine from entering into sleep/standby, and this is an effective solution.</sup>
3. Add `mem_sleep_default=deep` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, ensuring memory is completely recorded to the storage device when entering sleep. You may now have something like this

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1 mem_sleep_default=deep"
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** This has generally been the setting I've needed to configure in order to resolve the external keyboard issue.</sup>
4. Save the file
5. Update Grub:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
6. Reboot.

This should ensure the notebook enters a proper sleep state, allowing it to now properly respond to `wake` actions.

Comment: I indeed have an nvidia gpu and it has been my main source of linux related grief since day one. I suspect it was it again. Regardless, I can confirm your answer worked like a charm. Thanks a million!