# Nonresponsive black screen after left idle for

Tags: 20.04, suspend, hibernate

I am running Ubuntu (20.04 LTS) on my laptop (Asus ZenBook 13 OLED UX325) and I enjoy it for the most part. However, there I have one issue that is driving my crazy. If the laptop is left idle for a period of time, the screen turns black and it is impossible to undo it after it enters some sort of hibernation or sleep (or suspend?) mode. In other words, it enters some sort of sleep mode, and will not wake up when any buttons are pushed. The only solution forcibly turn off the laptop using the power button. This only occurs if it is left idle for a sufficient amount of time -- if I am quick enough after the screen turns black, I am able to press any key and log in normally.

Do anyone have an idea how to fix this for my specific laptop? I tried adding `nouveau.modeset=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` from this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442057/ubuntu-18-04-wont-wake-after-screen-lock-and-blank-suspend-sleep) without any luck.

---

Edit (added `/var/log/syslog` as requested by @matigo in the comments):

```
Jan  6 15:40:35 abc-ZenBook-UX325UA-UM325UA avahi-daemon[743]: Interface wlp1s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan  6 15:40:35 abc-ZenBook-UX325UA-UM325UA NetworkManager[752]: <info>  [1641480035.2654] device (wlp1s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan  6 15:40:35 abc-ZenBook-UX325UA-UM325UA wpa_supplicant[787]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
Jan  6 15:40:35 abc-ZenBook-UX325UA-UM325UA nm-dispatcher[4283]: run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon: No such file or directory
Jan  6 15:40:35 abc-ZenBook-UX325UA-UM325UA wpa_supplicant[787]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp1s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Jan  6 15:40:35 abc-ZenBook-UX325UA-UM325UA systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jan  6 15:40:35 abc-ZenBook-UX325UA-UM325UA systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Jan  6 15:40:35 abc-ZenBook-UX325UA-UM325UA systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Jan  6 15:40:35 abc-ZenBook-UX325UA-UM325UA kernel: [ 2959.035172] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Jan  6 15:40:35 abc-ZenBook-UX325UA-UM325UA systemd-sleep[4290]: Suspending system...
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Jan  6 16:01:53 abc-ZenBook-UX325UA-UM325UA systemd-modules-load[382]: Inserted module 'lp'
Jan  6 16:01:53 abc-ZenBook-UX325UA-UM325UA systemd-modules-load[382]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Jan  6 16:01:53 abc-ZenBook-UX325UA-UM325UA systemd-modules-load[382]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Jan  6 16:01:53 abc-ZenBook-UX325UA-UM325UA systemd-modules-load[382]: Inserted module 'msr'
Jan  6 16:01:53 abc-ZenBook-UX325UA-UM325UA systemd-sysctl[399]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/all/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
```

NB! I pushed many buttons for it to be easier to locate in the vast `/var/log/syslog` file.

Comment: It sounds like the notebook is not reaching a proper sleep state but instead getting stuck right before it. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1385323/1222991) might solve your issue 

Comment: Thank ytou, @matigo. It is however not quite the same problem because in my case it does not work with the built-it keyboard.

Comment: It's not so much the keyboard issue as the pause right before sleep. This is something I've seen on Dell, HP, and Asus computers over the years. That said, if it doesn't work, then it doesn't work. Another solution may present itself 

Comment: Thank you again for your willingness to help, @matigo. I did as specified in the answer but it did not work for me. Is this a computer specific problem?

Comment: I added `nouveau.blacklist=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` which appears to work even though the screen never appear to be sleeping as the cursor is always active. I sm however unsure if this good practice and a sustainable solution.

Comment: Adding to `nouveau.blacklist=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` perhaps elongated the time before it becomes nonresponsive but did alas not solve the problem as it occurred again.

Comment: Is there anything n your `/var/log/syslog` file from around the time of going idle that might point to the problem?